# Oracle PL/SQL Obtener nombre de package

Tags: oracle

tengo N Packetes con N Procedures, como puedo obtener el nombre del package que esta ejecutando el procedure, se que puedo obtener el nombre del procedure con $$PLSQL_UNIT, pero como hago lo mismo pero para el nombre del package, esto con el objetivo de armar una cadena que tenga "NombrePackage.NombreProcedure"

Ejemplo, tengo un paquete PCKXYZ con un procedure proc1, en el begin del procedure proc1 necesito alguna linea que me permita obtener el nombre del paquete dentro del cual esta el procedure que estoy ejecutando, o sea que me devuelva el nombre del paquete PCKXYZ.

Gracias de antemano y saludos a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto te puede servir:

> select    NAME  from all_source where 
>       owner = 'TU_USUARIO' and type =   'PACKAGE' AND   TRIM(UPPER(TEXT)) LIKE 'PROCEDURE BUSCADO%';

Answer (score 0):

Puede utilizar el siguente comando tambien puedes utilizar un like para hacer la busqueda agregandolo

select procedure_name
 from all_procedures

Esta otra forma intenta
 select procedure_name
 from all_procedures
 where owner = 'Tu'
 and object_name = 'Nombre_Paquete'

Comment: Mmmmm creo que no entendiste mi pregunta, necesito averiguar el nombre del paquete, NOMBRE DEL PAQUETE el cual contiene el SP que se ejecuta en un determinado instante.

Comment: Podrias postear el codigo de tu paquete